# How to include script tag inside react app based on environment variable

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to include a script tag with some code inside based on an environment variable on a react project.

Let's say that I want the following code to load if the certain env variable is matched.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var something = function() {
 // some code
}

something()

</script>
```

I can access the value of evn variable in the HTML file so I could create a script tag using `document.createElement('script')` dynamically based on the value but that way I am only able to create a script tag but not content inside the script tag. Is there any way I can create the script tag and also insert some code inside that script tag?

I basically want to load the script tag above including the code inside on domcontentloaded event.

Comment: Why can't you just execute the code *inside* the script tag within React?

Comment: You can `import` your script instead of creating DOM element with script. See [import](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import)

Comment: You can create content inside the result of `document.createElement('script')` by setting its `textContent` property...

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
 if(navigator.appName == 'Microsoft Internet Explorer') {
    document.write("<script tag here>");
 } else {
 document.write("<other script tag here>");
 }
</script>
```

Another way is to define whatever source is and assign attributes dynamically using JS:

```
// Create 2 .JS files and apply whatever conditional logic here to 
set the src attribute
var src = navigator.appName == "Load one.js" ?
```

"one.js" : "two.js";

```
var script = document.createElement("script");
script.setAttribute("src", src);
document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(script);
```

And finally, if you're already using JQuery in your project you can use $.getScript() to load a JS file from the server using GET:  https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/

Answer (score 1):

Its support [ejs](https://github.com/tj/ejs) there although.
add this in head tag, it works-

```
<% if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') { %>
  <script>
    // my GA script
  </script>
<% } %>
```